# MySQL Insert using PDO is not inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anybody explain to me why my insert function in MySQL is not inserting data into the database? There are no errors/warnings but my data is not successfully inserting.

```
function add_update_visitor_information() {
    include 'config.php';

    var_dump($conn);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO visitor_contacts (
            'salutation_dr/mr/ms', 
            first_name, 
            middle_init, 
            last_name, 
            suffix, 
            email
        ) VALUES (
            :salutation, 
            :firstname, 
            :middleinitial, 
            :lastname, 
            :suffix, 
            :email
        )"
    );

    echo '<br><br>'.$_POST['salutation'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['firstname'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['middleinitial'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['lastname'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['suffix'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['email'].'<br><br>';

    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':salutation' => $_POST['salutation'],
        ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
        ':middleinitial' => $_POST['middleinitial'],
        ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
        ':suffix' => $_POST['suffix'],
        ':email' => $_POST['email']
    ));

    var_dump($stmt);

    echo '<br><br>Adding or Updating!';
}
```

Here is my output:

```
object(PDO)#1 (0) { } 

test
yo
yo
yo
test
test@test.com

object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(180) "INSERT INTO visitor_contacts ('salutation_dr/mr/ms', first_name, middle_init, last_name, suffix, email) VALUES (:salutation, :firstname, :middleinitial, :lastname, :suffix, :email)" } 

Adding or Updating!
```

I'm pretty confused!

Comment: Pretty sure `'salutation_dr/mr/ms'` should be ``salutation_dr/mr/ms`` (back ticks not quotes). Also make sure your pdo object is set to throw exceptions when it errors.

Comment: `ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)`  Escape that title column (or rename it) with backticks, not quotes.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @bassxzero, if you make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure `'salutation_dr/mr/ms'` should be `salutation_dr/mr/ms` (back ticks not quotes). Also make sure your pdo object is set to throw exceptions when it errors.

Answer (score 0):

using `salutation_dr/mr/ms` as column name is not suggested but if you want to use this as column name you can try using back ticks ` in your query